# Identify slow and lagging queries in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We have a system that was running smooth but suddenly we had system lagging due to high CPU usage for around 3 hours. Now, I need to identify the exact queries or whichever the objects that affected the system for that exact time period. I am using Redgate Monitoring and it didn't show any logs or queries for that exact time. How am i suppose to identify the issue?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no other monitoring in place and you haven't enabled Query Store, your options are somewhat limited.

First, and easiest, you can look at the Dynamic Management Views such as sys.dm_exec_query_stats. That DMV shows you an aggregation of the queries currently in cache. From that you can get some idea of the queries that are running long, are frequently called, etc.. However, what it doesn't give you are specifics to a time frame (that three hour period, four hours ago), just a total aggregation. Further, the data in the DMV is completely dependent on the cache, so it might not have the same queries that were causing you problems.

Second, about your only other choice without having monitoring set up is to look at the blocked queries inside the System_Health Extended Event Session. [I've got a blog post](https://www.scarydba.com/2020/03/09/extended-events-system_health-and-a-long-running-query/) on how you can get at that data. This will show you specific time frames, so you can narrow down what you're looking at and get granular. The issue is, depending on the load on your system, those files may have turned over and the data may be lost.

Best thing you can do is look to setup monitoring on your systems so that you can see this stuff as its going wrong rather than trying to play catch-up after the fact.